# Testing Material UI Drawer's close on escape functionality with RTL in React 16

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am trying to test Material UI Drawer. When you press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or click outside the drawer it should close. But it is failing.
I am using react testing library for testing. I have created a codesandbox and I'm using **React 16.9.0** as well.

[sandbox with index.js open](https://codesandbox.io/s/drawer-testing-dr6q9n)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the way I solved it was make sure the the "Escape" key bubbles up. Also to make your test easier, assign `datat-testid` for the list content. You can call it `data-testid="list-component"`  Here is test example based on your code:

```
  it('closes drawer on escape key', () => {
    // render
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<TemporaryDrawer />);

    // open drawer
    fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('right-btn'));
    expect(queryByTestId('list-component')).toBeInTheDocument();

    // close drawer
    fireEvent.keyDown(queryByTestId('list-component'), { key: 'Escape', bubbles: true });
    expect(queryByTestId('list-component')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```